# Update Inner Join Where MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, where-clause

On table 'tb2' there's column 'date' and key column 'stake_code', linked to table 'tb1'.
On table 'tb1' there's key column 'code' and column 'is_customer'

**I wish to update 'date' field, setting it to '2012-12-02' for every matching 'code' and 'stake_code' key fields, where 'is_customer' condition is obeyed.**

Tried many different shapes, including this one:

```
UPDATE tb2
FROM
tb2 INNER JOIN tb1
ON stake_code = code
SET date = '2012-12-02'
WHERE
tb1.is_customer = "T"
limit 10000
```

[localhost] ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

*Thanks so far.*

Comment: date is a reserved word in SQL so you need to use backticks `

Comment: remove the FROM and give it another go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `FROM` part.

```
UPDATE tb2
INNER JOIN tb1 ON stake_code = code
SET date = '2012-12-02'
WHERE tb1.is_customer = 'T'
limit 10000
```